# Pandas Interpolation Method 'Cubic' - spline or polynomial?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, interpolation

I am trying to understand interpolation in pandas and I  don't seem to understand if the method 'cubic' is a polynomial  interpolation  of  order 3 or a spline. Does anybody know  what  pandas uses behind that method?

Comment: The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) states that `'cubic'` gets passed to [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html). That documentation states that it's a spline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In interpolation methods, 'polynomial' generally means that you generate a polynomial with the same number of coefficients as you have data points. So, for 10 data points you would get an order 9 polynomial.

'cubic' generally means piecewise 3rd order polynomials. A sliding window of 4 data points is used to generate these cubic polynomials.